# JSON.stringify child array is empty on Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

There are a lot of these types of questions, and looking at all of them, I'm not particularly sure what the difference is with my setup.

I've tried a few different variations of the ajax data and how to format the `JSON`, but this seems to get me the closest. I've done this quite a few times before, and I never ran into this issue.

When I hit the controller, `modelDetails` is a full object, and `ScopeRecord` is populated with data. However, each child array is empty -- including `ProcedureFields`, which isn't making sense. It's not `null`, but the count is 0.

Simplified js:

```
$("#submitButton")
    .click(function() {
    var result = {};
    result.ScopeRecord = {};
    result.ScopeRecord.ReferenceNumber = "testing123";
    result.RoomFields = [];
    result.BioFields = [];
    result.ReprocessingFields = [];
    result.CultureFields = [];
    result.ProcedureFields = [];

    var fieldInfo = {};

    //examDate
    fieldInfo.FieldID = 1;
    fieldInfo.FieldValue = "test me";
    fieldInfo.ItemHistoryID = 3;
    fieldInfo.AssociationID = 2;
    fieldInfo.IsModified = 1;
    result.ProcedureFields.push(fieldInfo);
    result.ProcedureFields.push(fieldInfo);
    result.ProcedureFields.push(fieldInfo);

    var options = {};
    options.url = "/MyController/SaveDetails";
    options.type = "POST";
    options.traditional = true;
    var test = JSON.stringify(result);
    options.data = test;
    options.contentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    options.dataType = "json";
    $.ajax(options);
});
```

My data on the request:

```
"{
    "ScopeRecord":
    {
        "ReferenceNumber":"testing123"
    },
    "RoomFields":[],
    "BioFields":[],
    "ReprocessingFields":[],
    "CultureFields":[],
    "ProcedureFields":
        [{
            "FieldID":1,
            "FieldValue":"test me",
            "ItemHistoryID":3,
            "AssociationID":2,
            "IsModified":1
         },
         {
            "FieldID":1,
            "FieldValue":"test me",
            "ItemHistoryID":3,
            "AssociationID":2,
            "IsModified":1
         },
         {
            "FieldID":1,
            "FieldValue":"test me",
            "ItemHistoryID":3,
            "AssociationID":2,
            "IsModified":1
         }]
  }"
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveDetails(RecordDetails modelDetails)
{
     ....
}
```

Model:

```
public class RecordDetails
{
    public ScopeRecord ScopeRecord { get; set; }
    public List<FieldInfo> ProcedureFields = new List<FieldInfo>();
    public List<FieldInfo> RoomFields = new List<FieldInfo>();
    public List<FieldInfo> BioFields = new List<FieldInfo>();
    public List<FieldInfo> ReprocessingFields = new List<FieldInfo>();
    public List<FieldInfo> CultureFields = new List<FieldInfo>();
}

public class FieldInfo
{
    public int ItemHistoryID { get; set; }
    public int FieldID { get; set; }
    public string FieldValue { get; set; } 
    public bool IsModified { get; set; }
    public int? AssociationID { get; set; } 
}
```

I've tried `options.data = { modelDetails : JSON.stringify(result) };` but that gives me a 500 error.

What part am I missing?

Comment: I've encountered 500 error yesterday and the problem was my parameter is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DefaultModelBinder` cannot set the value of fields. You need to make your collections properties by adding a getter/setter

```
public class RecordDetails
{
    public ScopeRecord ScopeRecord { get; set; }
    public List<FieldInfo> ProcedureFields { get; set; }
    public List<FieldInfo> RoomFields = { get; set; }
    ....
```

Comment: Completely overlooked that. Thanks.